# Is there a way to consume unit of work pattern mutlithreaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, entity-framework, unit-of-work

I'm consuming my repository services through unitOfWork throught the app.
But when I tried to make several DB calls simultaneously, DbContext threw an exception, saying:

```
different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext
```

that is true since I'm making 3 DB requests at the same time:

```
        var insertYekkaTask = unitOfWork.YekkaRepository.InsertAsync(new(data.AdvertID, data.MatchID));
        var getMatchTask = matchService.GetAsync(data.MatchID);
        var getAdvertTask = advertisementService.GetAsync(data.AdvertID);

        await Task.WhenAll(insertYekkaTask, getMatchTask, getAdvertTask);

        var yekkaId = insertYekkaTask.Result;
        var match = getMatchTask.Result;
        var advertisement = getAdvertTask.Result;
```

Now as you read from the title, Is there a way to consume unit of work pattern mutlithreaded or on some similar way?

Thanks.

Comment: You should not be creating your own unit of work and repositories if you are using EF. Do some research online and you'll see that and why. Basically, the `DbContext` IS a unit of work and each `DbSet` is a repository. You are doing it wrong. Each service should create its own `DbContext` as it is specifically designed to only be used in a single-threaded environment.

Comment: Thanks man! That was helpful! there is small refactoring waitting for me.

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework has the limitation of only being used for one request at a time (per db context). This is actually a limitation of the on-the-wire protocol used by many (most?) database engines: when one query is running, the same connection cannot run a different query until that query completes.

So, if you want to do multiple concurrent queries - whether using multithreading or asynchronous code - you'll need multiple EF db contexts.

Comment: Thanks man! You helped! I'll do a bit of refactoring now